# Generic WCF Wrapper

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, entity-framework

I'm using entity framework and i want to expose some methods via wcf services;

i have this function (On cs page)

```
 using (ICRMEntities oContext = RemClient.Create<ICRMEntities>())                
     oContext.FindByKey<DataLib.Models.CRM.ActivitySLA>("ActivitySLA", SLAID);
```

the content of this function is

```
   public static T FindByKey<T>(this IQueryable<T> oQuery, int keyValue) where T : EntityObject, ISimpleBaseClassMD
        {
            return oQuery.FindByKey<T>(keyValue, null);
        }
```

the interface defined in WCF service as:

```
public interface ICRMEntities : IDisposable, IContextWithUser
    T FindByKey<T>(string sObjectTypeCode, int keyValue, bool bRequestValue) where T : EntityObject, ISimpleBaseClassMD;
```

there is a problem with this generic method in WCF;
how can i wrap this method to save this functionalty?

Answer (score 3):

You can not.

You can not expose generic methods via WCF services. You need to define the type that will be used. This is a limitation of SOAP.

But, you can create a base class as the return type and add `KnownType` attributes to the service to define which derived classes this service can return.

Something similar to;

```
[KnownType(typeof(SomeClass))]
public interface ICRMEntities : IDisposable, IContextWithUser
    EntityObject FindByKey(string sObjectTypeCode, int keyValue, bool bRequestValue)
```